# Reactjs Copy to Clipboard that works for Excel Pasting (react-copy-to-clipboard)

Tags: excel, reactjs, copy-paste

I'm racking my brain on this and just can't seem to get an answer so would love some help.

I'm using a react library called Copy to Clipboard "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard"
Its great where I've been assigning copy info as text:

```
  <CopyToClipboard
  format={"text/html"}
    text={
    text1+"\t"+text2+"\t"+text3+"\t"
    }
  >
    <button className="btn-agnt">Copy</button>
  </CopyToClipboard>
```

What I'm hoping to do though, is to add a delimiter ("\t") so that I can copy and paste this into excel and it would paste across cells (text1 in cell 1, text 2 in the next cell etc). Just like a lot of other information gets copied and pasted into excel.

The issue I'm having is excel pastes into a single cell with the tab delimiter out and I just get a single cell of text. Does anyone know a delimiter that would work? Preferably a white space one so it looks fine to paste into word/notepad also?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies all, I spent forever on this, only to write it up on stack Overflow and then directly find the answer. Someone noted in a previous stackoverflow thread that the library automatically wraps in some HTML.
I looked closer into the docs and learned how to use the options section properly and changed it to the string "text/plain". Works great now and copies directly into excel as expected.

Thought I'd leave this here as I couldn't find the direct answer online and the other user ended up creating their own copy/paste method.

```
  <CopyToClipboard
  options={{format: "text/plain"}}
    text={
    text1+"\t"+text2+"\t"+text3
    }
  >
    <button className="btn-agnt">Copy</button>
  </CopyToClipboard>
```

Thanks everyone.